# Can't reopen the keyboard in the react-native-gifted-chat on android

Tags: android, react-native, keyboard, expo, react-native-gifted-chat

I am using a so simple GiftedChat component in react native on expo, the problem here is when i open the first time the keyboard this works fine, but the second time i press in the textInput but the keyboard doesn't appear, i'm using a emulator of android 5 and a device with android 7. Doesn't work in any

```js
import { useState, useLayoutEffect, useCallback } from 'react'
import { TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native'
import { GiftedChat } from 'react-native-gifted-chat'
import {
  collection,
  addDoc,
  orderBy,
  query,
  onSnapshot
} from 'firebase/firestore'
import { signOut } from 'firebase/auth'
import { auth, database } from '../config/firebase'
import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native'
import { AntDesign } from '@expo/vector-icons'
import colors from '../colors'

export default function Chat() {

  const [messages, setMessages] = useState([])
  const navigation = useNavigation()

  const onSignOut = () => {
    signOut(auth)
    .catch(err => console.log('Error logging out: ', err.message))
  }

  useLayoutEffect(() => {
    navigation.setOptions({
      headerRight: () => (
        <TouchableOpacity
          style={{
            marginRight: 10
          }}
          onPress={onSignOut}
        >
          <AntDesign 
            name='logout'
            size={24}
            color={colors.gray}
            style={{
              marginRight: 10
            }}
          />
        </TouchableOpacity>
      )
    })
  }, [navigation])

  useLayoutEffect(() => {
    const collectionRef = collection(database, 'chats')
    const q = query(collectionRef, orderBy('createdAt', 'desc'));


    const unsubscribe = onSnapshot(q, snapshot => {
      setMessages(
        snapshot.docs.map(doc => ({
          _id: doc.data()._id,
          createdAt: doc.data().createdAt.toDate(),
          user: doc.data().user,
          text: doc.data().text
        }))
      )
    })
    return unsubscribe
  }, [])

  const onSend = useCallback((messages = []) => {
    setMessages(previewMessages => GiftedChat.append(previewMessages, messages))

    const { _id, createdAt, text, user } = messages[0]

    addDoc(collection(database, 'chats'), {
      _id,
      createdAt,
      text,
      user,
    })
  }, [])

  return (
    <>
      <GiftedChat 
        messages={messages}
        showAvatarForEveryMessage={false}
        showUserAvatar={true}
        onSend={message => onSend(message)}
        messagesContainerStyle={{
          backgroundColor: '#fff'
        }}
        user={{
          _id: auth?.currentUser?.email,
          avatar: 'https://placeimg.com/140/140/any'
        }}
      />
    </>
  )
}
```

[gif example of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kyrzt.gif)
If you can help me with the reason why this happens i will thank you so much...

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the `TextInput` of `GiftedChat` (of `TextInput` in general actually) never looses focus if you dismiss the keyboard using the virtual Android button. Thus, the keyboard is not opened again if you simply retouch into the TextInput. If you touch outside it and then inside again, you will notice that the keyboard opens again. This should be the normal behavior of any `TextInput` and might be even expected by the user (we can open the keyboard again by pressing the same button).

However, you could try to handle this programmatically as well. The `GiftedChat` component provides a function to allow you to refocus the `TextInput` again programmatically. It is called `focusTextInput()` and it

> Open(s) the keyboard and focus the text input box

```js
const ref = useRef(null)

<GiftedChat
    …
    ref={ref}
/>
```

Then, call `ref.focusTextInput()`. We could then wrap the `GiftedChat` component inside a `Pressable` and fire this in the `onPress` function.

```js
const ref = useRef(null)

<Pressable onPress={() => ref.focusTextInput()}
<GiftedChat
    …
    ref={ref}
/>
</Pressable>
```

Answer (score 0):

**solution**: just dismiss keyboard to lose focus:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    const keyboardDidHideListener = Keyboard.addListener(
      'keyboardDidHide',
      Keyboard.dismiss,
    );

    return () => {
      keyboardDidHideListener.remove();
    };
  }, []);
```